# An application of intermediate value theorem to prove the existence of solutions

Tags: real-analysis

Let $f$ be a continuous function on $[0,1]$ with $f(0)=f(1)=0$. Prove that, for each $\alpha \in (0,1)$, there exists $x_1, x_2\in (0,1)$ such that $$f(x_1)=f(x_2)$$ with $x_1-x_2=\alpha$ or $x_1-x_2=1-\alpha$.

The main difficulty in this problem is that I don't know how to set a new function in order to apply intermediate value theorem? Any one can help me?

Comment: Is there a differentiability assumption concerning $f$?

Comment: No assumption on differentiability of $f$.

Comment: I guess the thing that you were going to need on this problem is intermediate value theorem instead of rolle .

Comment: You need differentiability on $(0,1)$ if you want to apply Rolle's theorem.

Comment: Sorry, I have edited the assumption. As @Amir Naseri, we just use mean value theorem.

Comment: Again, mean value theorem requires some form of differentiability. You mean intermediate value theorem, or somehow taking advantage of uniform continuity?

Comment: Start with the Extreme Value Theorem.

Comment: Hint: define $g\colon [0,2]\to\Bbb R$ by $g(x)=f(x)$ for $x\in[0,1]$, while $g(x) = f(x-1)$ for $x\in[1,2]$. (In other words, extend $f$ periodically to $[0,2]$.) Then consider $g(x+\alpha)-g(x)$.